# Hamiltonian positive definite and vacuum state

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, hamiltonian, vacuum

For the self-interating $\phi^4$ Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal L=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi \partial^\mu\phi-\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4,$$
the corresponding Hamiltonian is
$$H=\int d^3x (\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2+\frac{1}{2}\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla\phi+\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4).$$

I read that since every term in the Hamiltonian is postivie definite, the Hamiltonian will be bounded from below leading to a meaninful vacuum state.

Does this mean that there will be a ground vacuum state $|0\rangle$ with energy eigenvalue that is positive? Why does a positive Hamiltonian operator guarantee the existence of a ground state? Also, why does a positive Hamiltonian mean positive energy eigenvalues?

Comment: Positive-definite means by definition that all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: @NDewolf Given this Hamiltonian, how can we know that all its eigenvalues are positive? I can only see that the Hamiltonian when integrated is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $- \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is positive but it does not have a (normalisable) ground state.

In QFT, even the free Hamiltonian is not a well defined operator unless it is Wick ordered. It then has an isolated least eigenvalue. The interaction part is well defined in 1+1 dimensional space time if it is Wick ordered and has a space cut-off. The Hamiltonian with this interaction can be shown to be bounded below and have an isolated least eigenvalue. See, for example, [Summers' review](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3991), page 6.